# Adding extra space between equal sign or arrows automatically in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

There are some tools to clean Rstudio code (ctrl + shift + A for example) but I'm wondering if there is any shortcuts to make the code go from this:

```
plot(x = x.coord,
     y = data.mat[, MakeColName(metric, ptiles[1], "roiOpt")],
     ylim = ylim)
```

To

```
plot(x    = x.coord,
     y    = data.mat[, MakeColName(metric, ptiles[1], "roiOpt")],
     ylim = ylim)
```

or

```
verylongobject <- rnorm(19)
shortobj <- rnorm(39)
mobj <- rnorm(30)
```

to

```
verylongobject <- rnorm(19)
shortobj       <- rnorm(39)
mobj           <- rnorm(30)
```

or maybe some setting which makes it possible to adjust the spaces

```
verylongobject           <- rnorm(19)
shortobj                 <- rnorm(39)
mobj                     <- rnorm(30)
```

Comment: with `ctrl+i` you can align text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an RStudio Addin which provides this functionality:

https://github.com/seasmith/AlignAssign

Comment: This is perfect, also if someone wants the extra space as i the last example, just put comment a "<-" and the extra spaces in the beginning of the document.